# Javascript error messages difficult to understand

Tags: javascript, google-maps

There are a number of JavaScript error messages that I see on this page when I look with Chroms's JavaScript tool.  I am having trouble understanding why they happen. Here is the page:

http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/trailhead.php

Any idea what is the problem with it?

Comment: Please post error message here and explain what ur doing and what is not working. Don't just expect somebody else to do all the work for you

Comment: you have an error in your ajax, post it and will gethelp

Comment: @Thomas the error in the console is very gobbly-gooky and there are a few diff messages.  I am very novice in JS...will try to post relevant errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Console:

> **Uncaught TypeError:** Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null *trailhead.php:84*

trailhead.php:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function()
{
      if (request.readyState == 4)
      {
            var xmlDoc = request.responseXML;

            ...

            // obtain the array of markers and loop through it
            markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
```

xmlDoc is null, which means the request is either not receiving anything or not receiving valid XML. And it turns out to be the latter:

[trailhead_ajax.php](http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/trailhead_ajax.php):

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 21 at column 2381: attributes construct error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

In any case, the attribute construction error is because you had (formatted here for legibility):

```
<marker trailhead_name="Parrish Creek Trail" 
        trailhead_description="From Interstate 15 take Centerville exit 319.
                               Go east on Parrish Lane. At 700 East turn left
                               at the "T." Follow the narrow road to the
                               trailhead." />
```

You have to escape the `"T."` as `&quot;T.&quot;`.

Honestly, these error messages aren't difficult to understand. If anything, they're incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The one problem I see is invalid XML received by AJAX request. There are quotes which are not converted to HTML entities.

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: moz-nullprincipal:{ae7bee0f-3857-5344-ac34-31cd2a941e51} Line Number 21, Column 5841:

...t on Parrish Lane. At 700 East turn left at the "T." Follow the narrow road t...
...-------------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your ajax call is status ok before you try to access the data

```
if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
```

Also your xml response is not well formed

http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/trailhead_ajax.php
gives an error.